# Should you disable SSH login with root on your server?

Tags: ssh, security, root

Someone told me to disable SSH login with root for security reasons. Might I ask, why is this necessary, exactly? Wouldn't setting a very long (20+ chars long), full-printable-ASCII range, random password be as safe? That would take billions of years to brute force using supercomputers.

Comment: This question is being voted to close as non-constructive - it is requesting opinion - see the [faq].  However, a reason for preventing root logins over ssh is because you are relying on the security of the remote system to be robust.  A simple keylogger can defeat any strong password.

Comment: @Paul but if someone is keylogging me he'll be able to access the server and invoke "sudo password" just as I did. I still don't get it.

Answer (score 4):

It is always good practice to disable root access to a publicly accessible server. Use SSH keys instead as the only way to access your server via root. Root should only be used in an emergency anyway.

You never know if in the future an exploit may be found for the login of your server. My friend's server was hacked as he had root access via the web and his Linux system had a security flaw if a certain character was entered as the password.

Rather than making a better door lock, don't give them a door.

Comment: +1 QOTW for "Rather than making a better door lock, don't give them a door."

Comment: I still don't get it. If someone exploited a security flaw to get the root password, he would be still able to use root by calling sudo from any user, so disabling root doesn't do anything on this case.